# T4 Controller Template to trigger View Generation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I have been using some customized MVC templates that really improve my productivity.  However, I would like to take it to the next level.

I generate a controller template for each table in my app.  The controller has Edit, List, Details, and Delete actions.  What I would like to do, is at the same time trigger the generation of the views for those actions.

Does anyone have a reference or have suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy to generate multiple files from a single T4 template, but it can be done. A good tutorial is [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/).

Comment: I will try this in the next couple days.

Comment: I am having trouble getting include directive to work with the MVC.  According to this http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/02/05/trying-to-extend-the-asp-net-mvc-t4-item-templates-to-create-multiple-files.aspx MVC templates were unable to use includes.  I wonder if it still (if not directly) is with MVC2, which is what I am using.

Comment: This did help. What I really wanted to do is to modify the MVC templates to do this.  However there are some limitations within the MVC Env.  Your tutorial really helped and I am going to make a completely custom T4 template for generating my generic code.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC Scaffolding have a look at this link

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/

Also I would invest in a Tool like the T4 Tangible Engineering editor the added intellisense is handy